# Problems in creation database table Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I've written my android app, it uses a database, here the onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
database.execSQL(CREATE_PARK_DETAILS);
insertParks(database);
database.execSQL(CREATE_DIARY);
}
```

On my Samsung Galaxy S2 it works, like on other 100 people phones which downloaded the app from the store. But, one user has problems on his Sony-Ericsson Xperia Arc (LT15i) with Android 2.3.4. So I gave to test the app to other people using different phone, one of these has the same problem on Android 4.1...an SQLException.
After that I figured out that on this devices the second table is not being created, but only the the first one.

Why?

CREATE_PARK_DETAILS:

```
CREATE TABLE cableparks (id int, name varchar(100), city varchar(100), state varchar(50), logo varchar(50), xCoord int, yCoord int, url varchar(100) DEFAULT '', street varchar(100) DEFAULT '', cap varchar(10) DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

CREATE_DIARY:

```
CREATE TABLE diary (id int, comment text, addDate long, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES cableparks (id));
```

LogCat:

```
08-21 21:29:01.402: E/SQLiteLog(12388): (1) no such table: diary
08-21 21:29:01.402: D/dalvikvm(12388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 176K, 7% free
10130K/10823K, paused 4ms+7ms, total 61ms
08-21 21:29:01.414: W/CursorWrapperInner(12388): Cursor finalized without prior close()
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     getFavorite
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: diary (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM diary WHERE id=31;
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.db.DatabaseManager.getFavorite(DatabaseManager.java:133)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.db.DatabaseManager.getPark(DatabaseManager.java:122)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.activities.SinglePark.onCreate(SinglePark.java:120)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 21:29:01.453: E/TAG(12388):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 21:29:01.496: D/AndroidRuntime(12388): Shutting down VM
08-21 21:29:01.496: W/dalvikvm(12388): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b35300)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emaborsa.cablePark/com.emaborsa.cablePark.activities.SinglePark}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.populate(ItemizedOverlay.java:312)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.map.route.LocationOverlay.addOverlay(LocationOverlay.java:21)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.activities.SinglePark.setViewValues(SinglePark.java:180)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at com.emaborsa.cablePark.activities.SinglePark.onCreate(SinglePark.java:129)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-21 21:29:01.504: E/AndroidRuntime(12388):     ... 11 more
```

GetFavorite method:

```
public FavoritePark getFavorite(int parkId) {
    FavoritePark favorite = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DIARY + " WHERE " + ID + "=" + parkId + ";";
    try {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int commentIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(COMMENT);
            String comment = cursor.getString(commentIndex);
            int addedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ADD_TIME);
            Date added = new Date(cursor.getLong(addedIndex));
            favorite = new FavoritePark(comment, added);
        }
        } finally {
            try { cursor.close(); } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "getFavorite", e);
    }
    return favorite;
}
```

Comment: Give us the queries "CREATE_PARK_DETAILS" and "CREATE_DIARY".

Comment: try creating database with this tutorial http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: and post more code as well as the logcat output

Comment: create database from this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I'll post the logcat later, actually on my phone it works fine.... i have to ask other people since I cannot reproduce the exception. However you could also try it by yourself. If you want you could download it from the market, it's called "cable parks".

Comment: Yesterday a guy told me to try to put the table names in square brackets... i didn't solve it.

Comment: I SOLVED IT....but i really don't understand how it is possible. IF i remove the foreign key from the second table, it works fine. Could someone of you explain how it is possible?